# I want to read all the element as well as the element which having some value ValueID field

Tags: c#, xml

I want to read all the element as well as the element which having some value ValueID field. Please guide me how can I do this in C# as I am using DataSet to read the XML.

Below is my XML from which I need to do the above task...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Jobs>
    <Job Action="Post">
    <AdvertiserName>University of Missouri - St. Louis</AdvertiserName>
    <AdvertiserType ValueID="15890">Agency</AdvertiserType>
    <Classification ValueID="6215">I.T. &amp; Communications</Classification>
    <SubClassification></SubClassification>
    <Country ValueID="247">United States</Country>
    <Location ValueID="15346">Missouri</Location>
    <Area ValueID="38701">Saint Louis </Area>
    <PostalCode>63121</PostalCode>
    <Language ValueID="120036">2057</Language>
    <ContactName>
    </ContactName>
    <EmploymentType ValueID="2163">Permanent</EmploymentType>
    <StartDate>2014-02-23T06:01:55.907</StartDate>
    <Duration></Duration>    
  </Job>
</Jobs>
```

Comment: There are some ways to work with XML in .NET. What have you tried? Look into [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and try something.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, look into `XDocument` to deal with XML in C#. For example :

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("path_to_xml_file.xml");
//or if you have XML string instead of file :
//var doc = XDocument.Parse("xml string here");
var elements = doc
                  //<Jobs>
                  .Root
                  //<Job>
                  .Element("Job")
                  //all element that is direct child of <Job>
                  .Elements();
foreach (var element in elements)
{
    //get current element name
    var name = element.Name.LocalName;
    //get text inside current element tag
    var value = element.Value;
    if(element.Attribute("ValueID") != null)
    {
        //get value of ValueID attribute
        var valueId = element.Attribute("ValueID").Value;
        Console.WriteLine("element name : {0}. Value = {1}. ValueID = {2}", name, value, valueId);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("element name : {0}. Value = {1}.", name, value);
    }
}
```